# Restart Docker container on inner process crash

Tags: docker, unix, crash, exit

## Update: Found secret cause - nodemon

The answer is just to set the container to restart on crash.  In development, I'm using nodemon which prevents the process from exiting on a crash - so I assumed that the process crashing didn't cause the container to exit.  My mistake.  The process crashing does in fact cause the container to exit when using `node` and not `nodemon`.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "development:service": "nodemon ./service/server.js",
    "production:service": "node ./service/server.js"
  }
}
```

## Original Question

How do I restart a docker container when a process **inside** the container crashes?

Would the best way be to set `--autorestart ON_FAILURE` for the container and then make the container crash when the inner process crashes?  If so, how do I force the container to crash when one of it's process crashes?

I'm using the image `node:10.15.3`.

Useful Link: [how to make a container restart if the container, itself, crashes](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-cloud/apps/autorestart/)

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.3 

ENV NODE_ENV development

# Create application directory.
RUN mkdir -p /src
WORKDIR /src

# Install app dependencies and build.
ADD . /src
RUN yarn install --force

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./run.sh"]
CMD [ "./run.sh" ]
```

### Processes (simplified)

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
user        13  0.0  0.1  17952  2840 ?        S    15:09   0:00 bash ./install.sh
user        72  0.5  3.2 889668 66728 ?        Sl   15:09   0:00 /usr/local/bin/node /opt/yarn-v1.13.0/bin/yarn.js start 
user        97  2.4  3.2 919992 65748 ?        Sl   15:09   0:01 /usr/local/bin/node ./service/server.js
```

Comment: Usually a container only has one process, and if that crashes, the container restart policy applies.  Are you doing something different where there are multiple processes?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes, I'm using dockerize to wait for a tcp connection, then it runs yarn install and finally starts the node process

Comment: Usually you'd run `yarn install` in your Dockerfile.  Can you add your Dockerfile, or any other relevant information to provide a [mcve], to the question?

Comment: Tried running the above but got an error stating that `run.sh` was not found. Are you able to reproduce this with only the content of your question above, or does it depend on files that we can't see here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the --restart flag for docker run command
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies---restart

Example:
`docker run --restart=on-failure my-image-name`

Or if you are using docker-compose then you `restart: on-failure` for the service 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart

Comment: This wont work in my particular scenario because my node process isn't process 1.  But maybe I just need to change how the container is run so that it is.

Comment: Are you running multiple processes on the same container? Because if you want to restart the whole container when a single container dies, then you can create an entrypoint shell script which can catch non-zero exit code from your node application and either stop the parent process (which would trigger the restart policy) or start up the node process

Comment: Yes I am, that may be the best solution for me.  I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

When you run multiple services in a container, and you are very, very sure you want this (it's best practice to run a single process in a single container), you may want a process supervisor (for example `systemd`) which restart any crashed process inside, or crash if any of it's supervised processes crash.

There are also some other, more lightweight, ways to accomplish this, like a wrapper bash script.

It's all described here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

**Edit after question was updated with Dockerfile:**

The easiest way is probably to make sure `run.sh` crashes if any of it's subprocesses crash. Then the container will crash, and optionally restart if you use `--restart=on-failure` in `docker run`.

Comment: Is there a better way to make a container that runs node where there's only one process?  Would the only way be to make a new image where `yarn install` has already run?  If so that would violate the best practice of using the base image, right?

Comment: If node is the only process, you might not need `run.sh`. What does `run.sh` do?

Comment: Literally just:
#!/bin/bash
yarn "start:$NODE_ENV"

Comment: A container stops (i.e. crashes) if the CMD that's running exists.So your container should already stop (i.e. crash) if the yarn command stops (i.e. node crashes). You simply need the `--restart=on-failure` flag for `docker run` to restart it automatically after a crash.